# The characteristics of the input data

Tags: unix, sed, grep

```
    * Each line consists of two fields, separated by a pipe '|', where
    * the first field is a comma-separated list of items, and
    * the second field is a tag.
```

This is my INPUT:

```
        100,210,354,462|acct
        331,746,50|mis
        90,263,47,14|sales
```

and required OUTPUT:

```
        100acct
        210acct
        354acct
        462acct
        331mis
        746mis
        50mis
        90sales
        263sales
        47sales
        14sales
```

Comment: This is not a contractor site, what did you try where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\s*//;:a;s/,\(.*|\(.*\)\)/\2\n\1/;ta;s/|//' file
```

Explanation:

1. `s/\s*//` remove whitespace at the front of the record.
2. `:a;s/,\(.*|\(.*\)\)/\2\n\1/;ta` replace each `,` by the last field and a newline
3. `s/|//` remove the `|`

To preserve whitespace use:

```
sed -r 's/(\s*)(.*\|)/\2\1/;:a;s/,(.*\|(.*))/\2\n\1/;ta;s/\|//;s/(\S+)(\s+)(\S+)/\2\1\3/g' file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '{s/^\([^a-z].*\),\([^a-z].*\),\([^a-z].*\),\([^a-z].*\)|\([^0-9].*\)$/\1\5\n\2\5\n\3\5\n\4\5/;s/^\([^a-z].*\),\([^a-z].*\),\([^a-z].*\)|\([^0-9].*\)$/\1\4\n\2\4\n\3\4/}' filename
```

Answer (score 2):

One way using `GNU awk`:

```
awk -F "[,|]" '{ for (i=1; i<NF; i++) print $i$NF }' file.txt
```

Results:

```
100acct
210acct
354acct
462acct
331mis
746mis
50mis
90sales
263sales
47sales
14sales
```

Answer (score 1):

use the following

```
sed 's/^\([^a-z].*\),\([^a-z].*\),\([^a-z].*\),\([^a-z].*\)|\([^0-9].*\)$/\1\5\n\2\5\n\3\5\n\4\5/g;s/^\([^a-z].*\),\([^a-z].*\),\([^a-z].*\)|\([^0-9].*\)$/\1\4\n\2\4\n\3\4/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\),\([0-9]*\),\([0-9]*\),*\([0-9]*\)\([,|]\)\(.*\)/\1\6\n\2\6\n\3\6\n\4\6/' input | sed '/^[a-z]*$/d'
```

this expression is give the correct output for you.